# Handle "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException"

Tags: java

How can I handle this? `marks[i][j] = s.nextInt();`

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

I want to get the marks of any Students from user then compute average and print the best student

```
public class Student {

Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

int numberOfStudents = s.nextInt();

private String[] firsstNames = new String[numberOfStudents];
private String[] lastNames = new String[numberOfStudents];
private int[] studentID = new int[numberOfStudents];


    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
        System.out.println(i + "  " + "What is Student first name ? ");
        firsstNames[i] = s.next();
        System.out.println(i + "  " + "What is Student last name ? ");
        lastNames[i] = s.next();
        System.out.println(i + "  " + "What is Student ID ? ");
        studentID[i] = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println(i + "  " + "how many courses ?  ");
        int courses = s.nextInt();

        int[][] marks = new int[numberOfStudents][courses];
        
        for (int j = 0; j < courses; j++) {

            System.out.println("enter the marks : ");
            marks[i][j] = s.nextInt();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `marks` variable needs to be outside your loop. You need to assign the array for courses for each student as you know how many courses they have.

Comment: I would trap this exception in your debugger and see why you are getting this Exception.

Comment: Can you also add an example of sample input and output? Not really sure what you're trying to do. Your code won't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, create marks[] outside your for loop.

Second, since "courses" integer is dynamic. It is better to not initialize number of column in "marks" array initially.

```
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        int numberOfStudents = s.nextInt();

         String[] firsstNames = new String[numberOfStudents];
         String[] lastNames = new String[numberOfStudents];
         int[] studentID = new int[numberOfStudents];

        //will store marks for each student
        int[][] marks = new int[numberOfStudents][];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + "  " + "What is Student first name ? ");
            firsstNames[i] = s.next();
            System.out.println(i + "  " + "What is Student last name ? ");
            lastNames[i] = s.next();
            System.out.println(i + "  " + "What is Student ID ? ");
            studentID[i] = s.nextInt();
            System.out.println(i+1 + "  " + "how many courses ?  ");
            int courses = s.nextInt();
            marks[i] = new int[courses];


            for (int j = 0; j < courses; j++) {
                System.out.println("enter the marks : ");
                int input = s.nextInt();
                marks[i][j] = input;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<numberOfStudents;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<marks[i].length;j++){
                System.out.print(marks[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
       s.close();
```

Comment: It would be a better practice to close the scanner object i.e; s.close();    to avoid resource leak .